# Making an array of a certain struct within the struct.

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a structure called scene. Within the structure called scene, I need to make an array of other scene objects. Is this possible?

Comment: What meaning would such a class have: `struct X { X a };`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Think of X as of box, which has other boxes inside.

Comment: @RomanB.: No, it's a box that has the same box inside itself, and so on.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm.. that is ok, actually. The only problem is you cannot limit this recursion as you would in case if *a* was a pointer, right? (then *a* will be set to *NULL*)

Comment: @RomanB. yeah, it's like `X` is a box which has one `X` inside it. Then that `X` inside it will have another `X` inside it, and so ad infinitum. With a pointer, you just say "I will be remembering the address of an `X` at some point"

Comment: @RomanB.: The point of my Farnsworthian analogy was that the such a data structure doesn't make sense in terms of any abstract finite computing machine, and that the OP can realise the impossibility of her proposal just from this simple though experiment.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes, something like that. The box can contain anything as long as none of the content contains another box of the very same type. The "address-of" another box is perfectly OK. You can even consider this: `struct SelfX { SelfX & sx; SelfX() : sx(*this) { } };` No problem. Linux users do this all the time when they say `cd ././.`.

Comment: @KerrekSB http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll :)

Comment: @RomanB.: I had those when I was little, brought as a gift from Soviet Russia! Imagine how disappointed I would have been had I opened the doll and only found a reference...

Comment: @KerrekSB, mail order form :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because before `scene` is completely defined, the compiler doesn't know how big it is, and doesn't know what size to make the array.

However, you can have an array of *pointers* to `scene`, because pointers (not counting pointers to members and other oddities - thanks Nawaz) are all the same size:

```
class scene {
    scene* array[20];
};
```

Alternatively, you can store a pointer that will point to a dynamic array allocated with `new[]` and deallocated with `delete[]`:

```
class scene {
    scene() : array(new scene[20]) { }
    ~scene() { delete[] array; }

    scene* array;
};
```

or even more alternatively, store a `vector<scene>`, a `vector` of `scene`s:

```
class scene {
    vector<scene> array;
};
```

and with `vector`, you get a resizable array with no manual memory management.

Comment: Don't know, I've just upvoted two answers, one starting with "yes", the other with "no". I feel stupid, but both are correct :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I just took the word "array" more literally than Nawaz did :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `because pointers are all the same size`. Not all pointers are *necessarily* of same size. He can use *pointers*, not because "*pointers are all the same size.*", rarher because the compiler already knows the size (whatever it is) of pointer *of particular type*.

Comment: @Nawaz wow really? I thought that for any type `T`, `sizeof(T*) == C` where `C` is a constant integer. How does the compiler know how big the pointer will be to that particular type if it's not defined yet? Or what would make one pointer bigger and one smaller than another? And if that's true, you can't cast _any_ pointer to any other type of pointer without possible loss of information, right?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Because the "yes" answers all say "yes, you can do that, if by 'that' you mean something entirely different, which is in fact possible".

Comment: @SethCarnegie: When I wrote my previous comment, I had *pointer-to-member* as an example whose size may or may not be equal to `sizeof(T*)` where `T` is either fundamental type, or class type. It is because *pointer-to-member* are not pointers in the first place; for many compilers, they are basically struct which usually has two members : one offset, and other is pointer! So `sizeof(ptrMember)` would be equal to `sizeof(underlyingStruct)`. Sounds strange?

Comment: @Nawaz ah ok, I understand what you meant. Thanks. And no, doesn't sound that strange :) this is C++ after all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do that. But you've to declare the member as *pointer* as:

```
struct scene
{
     //other members

     scene *children; //this is what you need.
                      //you cannot make it like : scene children[100];
};
```

Then create the dynamic array as:

```
scene parent;
parent.chidren = new scene[100]; //100 children!
```

Just remember that you've to allocate and deallocate the memory yourself.

Alternatively, you can use `std::vector<scene*>`, or [`boost::ptr_vector<scene>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

Pseudocode:

```
struct Scene {
   int id;
   Scene* scenes;
};
```

PS. you could easily test this - do not be so lazy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you use `std::vector`. This is from some code I wrote yesterday:

```
#include <vector>
struct ChangeList // Tree of changes in a tree of values
  {
  int index ;
  std::vector<ChangeList> Changes ;
  } ;
```